# Unknown compiler options include & exclude

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I was making my first typescript-node-express application.

To start with, I created my own tsconfig file which looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modues"
    ]
  }
}
```

And inside my src/app.ts I am initialising my express app

```
import * as express from "express";

class App {

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
  }

  //TODO: What is public app: express.Application
  public app: express.Application;

}

const app = new App().app;
const port = 4040;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Now, When I do ts-node ./src/app.ts I am getting the following error

> error TS5023: unknown compiler option 'include'.
>
> error TS5023: unknown compiler option 'exclude'.
>
> ```
> at createTSError (/Users/an/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:245:12)
> at reportTSError (/Users/an/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:249:19)
> at Object.register (/Users/an/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:260:36)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/an/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:120:17)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)Unknown compiler
> ```

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

According to [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), `include` and `exclude` are supposed to be siblings of `compilerOptions`, not children:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modues"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The issue is because they do not belong in compiler options at all.

They should exist along-side compiler options like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modues"
  ]
}
```

See the examples here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples

Comment: thanks - this really solved it for me using angular 15 + ts 4.9.5 unbelievable how often I saw that wrong while browsing

Answer (score 3):

If you are **still** getting this error after 100% verifying that your `exclude` or `include` option is not within `compilerOptions` you may have forgotten to check both `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` which inherits from the former.

It's worth spending some time looking over the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig).